# determine the spectrum of the operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

determine the spectrum of the operator
$$-\Delta-5\phi^4,\phi=3^{1/4}(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}},x\in R^3$$

Comment: Could you explain the choice of the constants and what you expect?

Comment: The spectrum is purely absolutely continuous on $[0,\infty)$, and there are negative eigenvalues. Normally, one would not expect to be able to find these explicitly.

Comment: @Christian Remling How you see the presence of negative eigenvalues?

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: Actually, it's not clear immediately, I confused something (though my guess still is that there is negative spectrum, potential -5/3 near $x=0$ feels negative enough, but one would have to look at it more closely, using min-max).